# Can ffmpeg convert audio to raw PCM? If so, how?

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, pcm

I'm currently using `ffmpeg` to convert `FLV/Speex` to `WAV/pcm_s16le`, successfully.  However, I now need the output format to be RAW, that is, PCM signed 16-bit little endian, without the WAV header.  I tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.flv -vn -acodec pcm_s16le output.raw
```

But ffmpeg responds with:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'output.raw'
```

I also tried using `output.pcm` and `output` as output file names, with the same result.

I also tried the `-f` flag to specify raw format, but that gives:

```
Unknown input or output format: raw
```

Is this possible with FFmpeg?  If so, how?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le output.raw
```

You can get these options by running:

```
ffmpeg -formats
```

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types for details

Comment: for followers, ffmpeg -i lame1.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le yo.wav converts it to wav *with* the WAV headers.

Comment: For those stuck on `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'output.raw'`, note that the order of arguments is significant for FFmpeg, and hence you must keep the `-i` argument here as the first argument.

Comment: For me putting `-f s16le` after the codec was what worked.

Comment: If I add `-map 0:a` to encode all audios from input and change it to mkv, it gives a error... what would be the command to encode all audio tracks from input to pcm?

Answer (score 44):

convert `mp4` file to `pcm`

```
ffmpeg -y  -i input.mp4  -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 output.pcm
```

you can also use it to convert `mp3` to `pcm`

```
ffmpeg -y  -i input.mp3  -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 output.pcm
```

key params means:

```
-f s16le … PCM signed 16-bit little-endian samples

-ac 1 … 1 channel (mono)

-ar 16000 … sample rate 16000Hz
```

Comment: how-to convert mp3, m4a, aac files to wav A-law, 8000Hz, 64Kbps, mono ?