# How to convert an mp3 file to raw audio format using javascript

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg, file-processing, raw

I'm working on a project that involves song matching, so I am integrating with rapidApi's shazam endpoints. But the thing is, the song matching endpoint needs the audio snippet to be a base64 string of the audio in raw audio format. I know the API works. I downloaded a 3rd party application to do the conversion from mp3 to .raw, and converted it to base64 before making the request with it.

Now, I need to integrate this flow programmatically. How do I convert an mp3 or any audio source really to a .raw file? I've done a lot of searching but I can't find any solution.

Comment: Can be done with ffmpeg. Convert the audio file to raw and encode the content as base64 string.

Comment: Hi @Marc Figured as much. I can't find any resource on directions with which I can do that. Can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4854627/5781499 Spawn via node a child process, where you execute the command

Comment: Alright, I'd check this out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I used ffmpeg webassembly package for node and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with the [@ffmpeg/ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg) webassembly package. A javascript port of ffmpeg.

```js
const convertToRaw = async (filePath)=>{
    const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true })
    await ffmpeg.load();
    const file = await fetchFile(filePath)
    ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'input.mp3', file)
    await ffmpeg.run('-i', 'input.mp3', '-f', 's16le', '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-ac', '1', 'output.raw')
    const data = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'output.raw')
    const base64 = Buffer.from(data.buffer).toString('base64')
    return base64
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the web audio’s decodeAudioData is what you are looking for.

You want the PCM data, right?