# Is there a way to convert .wav files to .raw in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I want to use google speech api to convert audio files to string. But it seems that it only accepts .raw files.

Comment: https://henquist.github.io/0.5.2/coefficients_from_wav.html

Comment: `ffmpeg` can do this (it's not just for video files). There is a lot of information out there and I know it works with node.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-nodejs), check out this answer here to get started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4854627/8678978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to convert them. See the [Introduction to audio encoding](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding) documentation which discusses file formats vs encoding and shows the [Supported audio encodings](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding#audio-encodings).